# Embed the YouCamMakeup camera functionality

Tags: android, ios, image-processing, android-camera

I want to embed the [`YouCamMakeup`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CZpPg.png) camera functionality. In this app when i click on camera it detect the real time my face, eye brows and lips and give the option to change eye brows and lips color on live camera. I want to embed this functionality in my app, how i achieve this functionality or tell me any `FaceSDK` which provide me this functionality.

Here is the screen shot off real time makeover of this app.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `msqrd` for face `tracking` and `detection`. it is very reliable because Facebook purchases it means something interesting is in it..
[click here](http://msqrd.me/products.html) to go the link

Answer (score 1):

You have all you need on the apple dev website : https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/CoreImaging/ci_detect_faces/ci_detect_faces.html

```
    CIContext *context = [CIContext contextWithOptions:nil];                    // 1
    NSDictionary *opts = @{ CIDetectorAccuracy : CIDetectorAccuracyHigh };      // 2
    CIDetector *detector = [CIDetector detectorOfType:CIDetectorTypeFace
                                              context:context
                                              options:opts];                    // 3

    opts = @{ CIDetectorImageOrientation :
              [[myImage properties] valueForKey:kCGImagePropertyOrientation] }; // 4
    NSArray *features = [detector featuresInImage:myImage options:opts];        

for (CIFaceFeature *f in features)
{
    NSLog(NSStringFromRect(f.bounds));

    if (f.hasLeftEyePosition)
        NSLog("Left eye %g %g", f.leftEyePosition.x. f.leftEyePosition.y);

    if (f.hasRightEyePosition)
        NSLog("Right eye %g %g", f.rightEyePosition.x. f.rightEyePosition.y);

    if (f.hasmouthPosition)
        NSLog("Mouth %g %g", f.mouthPosition.x. f.mouthPosition.y);
}
```

And you can try this framework : https://github.com/kairosinc/Kairos-SDK-iOS

For Android you can try this : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/FaceDetector.Face.html (also the official dev android website ..)

You must do your research, we're not here to give you all you need when you need it.

Your question is tagged wth androuid AND iOS, next time be more specific please

Comment: Yup you are saying absolutely right. And i already check these links these not full fill my need.